# How to make POST call pass without the need of reloading the page?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I am subscribing to presence channel and get the below-given error:

> XHR failed loading: POST "http://127.0.0.1:8000/broadcasting/auth".

The `POST` request succeeds only after I reload the page(I've check the console). How to make it(POST call) pass without the need of reloading the page?

```
<tr v-for="user in users"> 
        <td>{{user.name}}</td>
        <td>{{user.ip}}</td>
</tr>
```

```
 data() {
    return {
        users:[]   
   }    
},   
 mounted() {
      window.Echo.join('privateChannel')
        .here(users => (this.users = users))
        .joining(user => (this.users.push(user)))
        .leaving(user => (this.users = this.users.filter(u => (u.id 
                                            !==user.id)))
     );  

 this.fetchData()
},

 methods: {
     fetchData(){
          axios
            .get('api/users')
            .then(res => (this.users= res.data))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
   },
 }
}
```

Comment: @acdcjunior  The same. The user shows up only when I reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `get` instead of `post`

Try this -

```
 fetchData(){
      axios
        .post('api/users')
        .then(res => (this.users= res.data))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: After I reload the page, I get
XHR finished loading: POST "http://127.0.0.1:8000/broadcasting/auth".{"auth": very long number,"channel_data":"{\"user_id\":2,\"user_info\":{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Kate\",\"email\":\"kate@mail.ru\",\"email_verified_at\":null,\"created_at\":null,\"updated_at\":null}}". So I get the response from my check function if user  can join the channel.